# Show hidden fields after failed form submission

Tags: jquery

I'm relatively new to jQuery. I have a form (https://jsfiddle.net/drewdeakin/zsu8khm4/2/) where 2 fields will show if the user selects 'other'.

If the user submits the form, and the form returns an error (form validation is handled with PHP), how can I get the hidden fields to show if the user had selected 'other'?

Here's the jquery that I am using:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.location-other').hide();
      $('.location').change(function(){
        if($('.location option:selected').val() == 'other') {
          $('.location-other').show();
        } else {
          $('.location-other').hide();
        }
      });

    });
```

The HTML Form pre submissions:

```
<form>

  <h2>Location</h2>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="business_id" class="label">Venue</label>
    <div class="select">
      <select name="business_id" class="location">
        <option value="3">Location 1</option>
        <option value="7">Location 2</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>

    </div>

    <div class="location-other">

      <p>
        <label for="event_location_name" class="label">Venue name</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" id="event_location_name" name="event_location_name" value="" />
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="event_location_address" class="label">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" id="event_location_address" name="event_location_address" value="" />
      </p>

    </div>

  </div>
  <p class="field">
    <button name="event_insert" class="button is-primary">Save and continue &rarr;</button>
  </p>

</form>
```

The HTML form post submission:

```
<form>

  <h2>Location</h2>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="business_id" class="label">Venue</label>
    <div class="select">
      <select name="business_id" class="location">
        <option value="3">Location 1</option>
        <option value="7">Location 2</option>
        <option value="other" selected>Other</option>
      </select>

    </div>

    <div class="location-other">

      <p>
        <label for="event_location_name" class="label">Venue name</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" id="event_location_name" name="event_location_name" value="Name" />
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="event_location_address" class="label">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" id="event_location_address" name="event_location_address" value="Address" />
      </p>

    </div>

  </div>
  <p class="field">
    <button name="event_insert" class="button is-primary">Save and continue &rarr;</button>
  </p>

</form>
```

Comment: Please edit your question & add PHP code also

Comment: use ajax call to submit your form data then use response to show values

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the question itself, preferably as a [mcve]. Your HTML is important here, don't make us go off site to find critical information. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you.

Comment: Please show your PHP code for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remember to print out the selected option in the form:

```
<option value="other" selected>Other</option>
```

Then you can check the selected location using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    check_location();

    $('.location').change(check_location);
});

function check_location() {
    if($('.location option:selected').val() == 'other') {
        $('.location-other').show();
    } else {
        $('.location-other').hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code. Also please check fiddle link in comment. If there is error in form you can prevent button action from triggering further code by using return false. So your form state will remain same and if you have selected other option then it will keep hidden fields in visible state only. If there is no error then you can continue with submit action. I assume you have a check for error already.

```
    <form>

  <h2>Location</h2>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="business_id" class="label">Venue</label>
    <div class="select">
      <select name="business_id" class="location">
        <option value="3">Location 1</option>
        <option value="7">Location 2</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>

    </div>

    <div class="location-other">

      <p>
        <label for="event_location_name" class="label">Venue name</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" id="event_location_name" name="event_location_name" value="" />
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="event_location_address" class="label">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" id="event_location_address" name="event_location_address" value="" />
      </p>

    </div>

  </div>
  <p class="field">
    <button id="saveData" name="event_insert" class="button is-primary"> Save and continue →</button>
  </p>

</form>

    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.location-other').hide();
      $('.location').change(function(){
        if($('.location option:selected').val() == 'other') {
          $('.location-other').show();
        } else {
          $('.location-other').hide();
        }
      });     
      $( "#saveData" ).click(function() {
        var isError = true;
        if(isError){
            return false
        }
        else{
            alert("submitted");
        }
      });

    });
```

Comment: Fiddle link for above answer https://jsfiddle.net/shivpatne/vj6aL2su/